# Custom role not listing in "Service Accounts"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

im trying to access firebase storage with google cloud library. But when i try to upload a file im getting this error: `xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.`

I guess i have to set some roles to this account. I created a custom role from google cloud platform.

[image]

[image]

But custom role is not listing in role list when i try to edit permissions in this profile.

Comment: Can you make sure whether you have followed all the steps mentioned in the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385902/service-account-does-not-have-storage-objects-get-access-to-the-google-cloud-sto)?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the custom role launch stage is "General Availability"